# getting ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer when using javax.xml.ws.Endpoint

Tags: jax-ws, java-7

I tried to use "javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;" publishing some WS like this:

`Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/ServiceWS", new ServiceWS());`

However, I keep getting the  "ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer" on server start-up. using JDK1.7 and JBoss 7.1.0. AFAIk the HttpServer is a part of JavaSE, so what could be the problem?

Comment: By any chance, are you using HttpServer in your code, or the error came as part of the JBoss startup?

Comment: Of course I'm not using that class directly as it is not under a java/javax/org package. The error appears during the JBoss start-up. The publish method is invoked inside a singleton bean's PostConstruct annotated method, with the bean marked as @Singleton.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLVED**: I had a small error in my project settings. Solved by removing the jaxws-rt.jar from the deployment assembly.

Answer (score 1):

> One justification for including [JAX-WS 2.x](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) as part of Java SE
>   6.0/7.0 instead of Java EE 5/6 is that web service delivery with JAX-WS
>   2.x does not require a servlet or EJB container.
>
> In use cases that do not require the full power of a commercial
>   HTTP server and servlet or EJB container, the Endpoint
>   class provides a convenient mechanism for components in software or
>   systems in tightly controlled environment to easily communicate
>   through web services. A second use of this mechanism is to
>   prototype and to develop production web services to be finally
>   deployed in Java EE containers.

[*JAX-WS Web Services Without Java EE Containers*](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/03/jax-ws-web-services-without-ee-containers.html)

If you already have a class with the `@WebService` annotation is not necessary that the `publish` method is invoked inside a singleton bean. JBoss scans the applications for annotations during the time of deployment and, if no errors, publish the web service.

Comment: That won't work, since the list of endpoints subject to publishing is known in my case only in run-time.